# Get all associated entity-attributes by patchEntity in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have the following problem. 
I have 2 tables:

- `articles (id, title, body, article_type_id, created, modified)`
- `article_types** (id, name)`. (There is already some data in the `article_types` table)

I also have an `ArticlesController`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

class ArticlesController extends AppController {

    public function create() {
        $article = $this->Articles->newEntity();

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->data(), [
                'associated' => ['ArticleTypes']
            ]);

            dump($this->request->data);
            dump($article);

        }

        $this->set('article', $article);
        $this->set('articleTypes', $this->loadModel('ArticleTypes')->find('list')->toArray());
    }

}
```

An **ArticlesTable**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ArticlesTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->belongsTo('ArticleTypes', [
            'foreignKey' => 'article_type_id',
            'className' => 'ArticleTypes',
            'propertyName' => 'article_type'
        ]);

    }

}
```

And a **create.ctp**:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($article) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('title') ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('body', ['type' => 'textarea']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('article_type.id', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => $articleTypes]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('send') ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

If I spend the data in the Controller, it looks like this:

**$this->request->data**

```
array:3 [▼
  "title" => "abcdefg"
  "body" => "abcdefghsdflösdfklösdfsddfghdfgd"
  "article_type" => array:1 [▼
    "id" => "3"
  ]
]
```

**$article**

```
Article {#101 ▼
  +"body": "abcdefghsdflösdfklösdfsddfghdfgd"
  +"article_type": Entity {#127 ▼
    +"id": 3
    +"[new]": true
    +"[accessible]": array:1 [▶]
    +"[dirty]": array:1 [▶]
    +"[original]": []
    +"[virtual]": []
    +"[errors]": []
    +"[invalid]": []
    +"[repository]": "ArticleTypes"
  }
  +"[new]": true
  +"[accessible]": array:1 [▶]
  +"[dirty]": array:2 [▶]
  +"[original]": []
  +"[virtual]": []
  +"[errors]": array:1 [▶]
  +"[invalid]": array:1 [▶]
  +"[repository]": "Articles"
}
```

As you can see in `$article`, in the attribute `"article_type"` is only the id of the entity available.

Is it possible, that the name of `"article_type"` is automatically assigned by `patchEntity` of the `ArticleTypes`?

Comment: I didn't understant what you really want

Comment: Why exactly would you need that value? It's not required for neither the marshalling process, nor the saving process?

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a way in CakePHP that patchEntity returns the "Articles" object together with the corresponding "ArticleTypes" object because I want to pass the name of the "ArticleTypes" at $this->Flash->message().